# How to render component/helper from another one?

Tags: ember.js

I have render-component ( [source](https://github.com/vvscode/js--ember-render-helper/blob/master/helper/render-component.js) ) which used to render components/helpers from controller fields. It worked fine for ember 1.9.1 but after updating up to ember 1.12.1 I found changes in API. After [updating code](https://gist.github.com/vvscode/33f84cabc917fd7ff1f3) I restore simple cases ( like render view by name from some property ). But largest part of functionality still broken.

I'm interesting about where can I read more about such things like

- env ( which used inside components/helpers internal implementation )
- morph ( I understand that it's a part of html-bars, but I'm interested in more documentation )
- hooks ?

Can anyone share some experience at creating such helper ? Or way to find solution in such cases? ( I mean that this things not fully documented )

P.S. I know about component-helper from ember 1.11 -- but it doesn't allow render helpers ( with params) and using it I should define all properties in template. And when name of component/helper is dynamic --  I should pass different params / attributes.

Thx in advance

P.P.S

Some examples of functionality I want restore with my helper ( more examples and motivation you can find at helper page -- I just want note difference between my helper and build-in component-helper ):

```
{{#render-component componentName _param='btn-component' action="addSection"}}
{{render-component 'pluralize-component' ___params=hash}} // hash = { count:ungrouped.content.meta.total, single:"Object"}
{{#render-component 'componentName' _param=paramName someOption=someOptionValue}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got quite a few questions here, but to answer the one in your title: Ember 1.11 introduced the [component helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_component-helper) that allows you to dynamically render components.

```
componentName: 'someComponentName'

...

{{component componentName param=value someAction='someMapping'}}
```

Comment: component helper allow render components but not helpers ( you can't pass argument into {{component}} -- that is the main question. Also you can't define structure of attributes from controller -- you should define it in template

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you then. Your best bet at reproducing the functionality you had before is to just read the source code. Ember's documentation for private parts of the view layer is extremely lacking. There isn't even much documentation in the source code itself.

Comment: I know, but there are a lot of complicated moments -- like Streams, Morph etc -- I broke my mind trying to debug and find some logic (. Thx anywhere

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/26/emberjs-dynamically-render-components/) contains most of the information one might use to implement what I *think* you're getting after (compared to the standard component helper).

One notable out-of-the-box solution they suggest is the use of the (*almost deprecated*) [dynamic-component addon](https://github.com/minutebase/ember-dynamic-component).

```
{{dynamic-component
  type=theType
  boundProperty=foo
  staticProperty="bar"
  onFoo="fooTriggered"
}}
```

Hopefully this (and other suggestions from the article) steer you towards your solution.

Comment: component helper allow render components but not helpers ( you can't pass argument into {{component}} -- that is the main question. Also you can't define structure of attributes from controller -- you should define it in template

Comment: Right. I think if you're looking to dynamically run helpers, you should just wrap them as components and use {{component}} Or if you have a Lot of them, just make a component that references all your helpers and does a switch/selection based on the params to the component.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this, ended up with a solution myself.

My scenario was that I wanted to pass in a component to another component and render it inside that component, which sounds like what this question was aiming for.

For those who don't clearly know how the `{{component}}` helper works:

Use it to render another component.
 `{{component "component-name" param1="value" param2="value"}}`

This would work exactly the same way as:
 `{{component-name param1="value" param2="value"}}`

---

For my scenario, I did this:

In the template invoking the first component:
 `{{my-comp-1 comp=(component "my-comp-2" param1="value" param2="value") other-param="value"}}`

In `my-comp-1`'s template, use the attribute used for the component:
 `{{component comp}}`

That was all I needed to do.

This works perfectly as of Ember 2.7.0.